# Annoying hint box in JetBrain IDE's

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, pycharm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

When I'm coding in JetBrains IDE's I get frustrated when I want to fix the code and hint box popup block my view where the vital information is few lines below my coding line. The popup blocks 1/4 of all horizontal space on my screen.
I don't like this.

Is it possible to make popup transparent so that I can see what is few lines below my editing line even when there is code hinting?

**I don't accept answers that are not refering to transperency.**
**And I don't want manualy start the hint popup!**

[image]

Comment: I am running IntelliJ version 11 and I cannot find a way to make the code completion dialog transparent.

Comment: There is no such option. I may only suggest to disable automatic popup and invoke code completion manually when needed (`Ctrl+Space` in most keymaps). This way you will have enough time/momentum to remember the text/code that will be covered by completion popup window.

Comment: "no such option" : Not accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transparent popup feature is not available at the moment. There is a feature request already submitted in 2014. You are welcome to comment/vote this request to be notified when(if) it's addressed: [IDEA-126993](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-126993).

Comment: Almost 8 years later, I'm still waiting for this feature. Breh...